# a charged particle path

Tags: electromagnetism, charge, homework-and-exercises

A particle of mass $m$ and charge $e$ enters a homogeneous and stationary electric field $E$ with velocity $v_0$ perpendicular to the direction of the field.
Calculate the particle's path?

What does it mean by 'path'? I tried integrating acceleration wrt time but I don't get the same result.

The correct answer is
Parabola with the parameter $\frac{m{v_0}^2}{eE}$

My attempt:
$\\ F=eE=ma$
$\\ \implies a=\frac{eE}{m}$
$\\ v= \frac{eE}{m}t+v_0$
$\\ s= \frac{eE}{2m}t^2+v_0t+c$

Comment: Hint, the initial velocity is perpendicular to the direction of the field, so make sure you keep components separate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you integrate acceleration w.r.t. time, you'll get the change in velocity. If you add the initial velocity to that and integrate again, you'll find the change in position. what they mean by calculate the "path" is find the function that describes its position w.r.t. time.

Comment: Sorry for my lack of elaboration, but I have actually integrated twice but i dont get any coefficient equal above. Also i edited the correct answer. But im not getting that.

Comment: Edit your question to include what you've done, then ask us about a specific concept. If your question is "what do they mean by 'path'?" That's okay and answered. If your question is "How do I get the right answer?" You might have troubles with regards to our homework policy.

Comment: I have edited the question

Comment: You accepted this answer.  Were you able to use this hint to get the correct answer, or are you still stuck?